# How do I create an attribute?

Tags: javascript, angular

In plain JavaScript I can create an element like

```
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.setAttribute('onClick', 'console.log(\'click\')');
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Now my question: Is there a way to create an angular 2 attribute? For example, I tried following with no success

```
btn.setAttribute('(click)', 'myFunction()');
```

I know I can't `$compile` in Angular 2 like AngulaJS. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 doesn't process HTML added dynamically.

`(click)="..."`, `[prop]="val"`, `{{}}` are only processed on markup added statically to a components template.

What you can do is create a component dynamically at runtime and insert it using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`.